# Is blocking SMTP ports prevent server from sending emails?

Tags: centos, security, firewall, smtp

I have a Centos server with cPanel on it.

Yesterday, some hackers had successfully connected to my smpt server and sent thousand of emails from it.

What I want to do is blocking every ports except for HTTP and HTTPS ports to everyone (IN and OUT), except to some ips (for admin purpose).

I've already did this for the past few months with smpt ports opened. This is working perfectly, but I want to know if blocking ports 25, 465 and 587 (IN and OUT) will prevent the server itself from sending emails. I have some php scripts which need to send emails.

I don't want any email accounts, so sending emails from a mail client is not necessary.

Comment: `I want to know if blocking ports 25, 465 and 587 (IN and OUT) will prevent the server itself from sending emails` - Yes it will. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: The server ip addresses are on the ignore list of the firewall, so these ports are not blocked for them. But does the recipient server has to access mine for some reason?

Comment: No, the recipient server does not need to connect to your server on ports 25, 465 or 587.

Comment: So allowing only the server ip addresses to access these ports will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMTP involves a conversation between two SMTP servers on port 25.  I'm going to copy and paste a sample conversation from [this website](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml), which is demonstrating testing SMTP with telnet:

```
telnet: > telnet mx1.example.com smtp
telnet: Trying 192.0.2.2...
telnet: Connected to mx1.example.com.
telnet: Escape character is '^]'.
server: 220 mx1.example.com ESMTP server ready Tue, 20 Jan 2004 22:33:36 +0200
client: HELO client.example.com
server: 250 mx1.example.com
client: MAIL from: <sender@example.com>
server: 250 Sender <sender@example.com> Ok
client: RCPT to: <recipient@example.com>
server: 250 Recipient <recipient@example.com> Ok
client: DATA
server: 354 Ok Send data ending with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
client: From: sender@example.com
client: To: recipient@example.com
client: Subject: Test message
client: 
client: This is a test message.
client: .
server: 250 Message received: 20040120203404.CCCC18555.mx1.example.com@client.example.com
client: QUIT
server: 221 mx1.example.com ESMTP server closing connection
```

If you only allow outgoing, it's going to be a short conversation.  Your server will never receive any replies from the remote SMTP server.

In other words:  Yes, it will block mail.

Comment: Only the `incoming` or `destination` side communicates on port 25. The `outgoing` or `source` side uses a port in the ephemeral port range.

Comment: @joeqwerty All SMTP server to SMTP server communication takes place over standard SMTP ports.  Clients can connect to standard SMTP ports from random ports.  Marm is sending mail from his CentOS server from PHP;  I presume he's coded it to use a local SMTP server rather than to connect to the SMTP servers of the individual recipients.  I could be mistaken, of course.

Comment: That is not the case. When my SMTP server sends an outgoing email it connects `FROM` an ephemeral port `TO` port 25 of the destination server. My server `does not` use port 25 for outgoing SMTP sessions. My server uses port 25 for `incoming` SMTP sessions, not `outgoing` SMTP sessions. If you have an email server handy you can confirm this with netstat. When we talk about application and service ports, in almost all cases, we're talking about the `destination` port, not the `source` port.

Comment: I do have an Exchange server, but netstat isn't providing that information.  ;)  Nor is Nagios.  Exchange is too busy with local mail;  Nagios isn't busy enough.  I actually went looking for documentation with a definitive answer before I replied to you the first time, but my google-fu is failing me.  So I'm going back to the depths of my memory (1995), where I could have sworn I was told it worked that way.

Comment: I like to run `netstat -a -n -o >c:\netstat.txt` to create a file with the netstat output for "offline" viewing. You should see connections from `local address:ephemeral port->foreign address:25` for `outgoing` email and `local address:25<-foreign address:ephemeral port` for incoming email.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing netstat > netstat.txt.  Am pouring over it now.  :)

Comment: All my connections involving port 25 either way were submissions (spam, LOL), so I got my friend to check.  I stand corrected.  And also stand by "No, you will not receive mail."  :)  At the very least, it's going to fail any site that uses sender verify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you block the port #. There will be no successful communication which is needed for that service to work.

Comment: The server ip addresses are on the ignore list of the firewall, so these ports are not blocked for them. But does the recipient server has to access mine for some reason?

Comment: If I let only the outgoing ports open, will it works?

Comment: I doubt it @Marm

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively instead of blocking the connections and un-blocking when needed (that's what it seems you want to do) you can stop the server and start it only when you need it, looks like a 'cleaner' option.

Comment: You can send email without the server running.  Depending on the setup, you depend on that fact for a stand alone Unix/Linux workstation to be able to send mail.

Comment: I know, if he just wants to send email he may as well turn off the mail server, or if he just needs local delivery he can run it binded locally, not clear on what he really wants to do